# What is the URL Scheme of the native Files App in IOS

Tags: html, ios, ipad

i am trying to run my webpage locally on my own ipad, offline. The Files App is rendering the html but i guess i would have to set up specific links to connect it with js and css?

or is there any other easy way to do this? it just needs to run on one ipad... not deployment or whatsoever.

Comment: Setup a local webserver on Mac/PC and open the webpage from Safari on iPad via http://192.168.0.1 or whatever you computer's IP is. iPad and computer should be on the same network

Comment: thank you. i have looked into this but would need to find a solution that works without having my mac close by...